# How to measure how fast I'm sending the UDP datagrams?

Tags: sockets, udp

I have two questions about the actual sending speed using sendto() with C socket programming.

1. I did a little socket programming and I'm sending UDP datagrams back to back with no spacing(pausing) between each sendto action in a for loop. Is it reasonable to use clock_gettime() to get the elapsed time and calculate the actual sending rate? What's actually influencing the sending speed, is it the CPU's frequency, or is it the network interface that I'm using? My understanding is that it should be the slower one of the two? And use clock_gettime(), can I get a rather good estimation of this sending speed? Say that we get this sending speed and denote it by S.
2. Suppose I'm sending the UDP datagram from a PC through a 100Mbps ethernet network interface to a router. What's the actual arrival rate at the router? For one case, if S is greater than 100Mbps, then the arrival rate will be around 100Mbps, right? If S is greater than 100Mpbs, then the arrival rate should be S, right? Or should it be still 100Mbps? I'm a a little confused.

And the reason I'm doing this is that I want to get the maximum burst size of UDP datagram I could send in a row to the router(given a certain bandwidth limit of the outgoing link) without dropping any datagram. Any idea how to do some tests to get this?

Answer (score 0):

A million things affect the speed and dropped packets. I recommend you write a C program that varies sending speed, row length, etc, measures speed and dropped packets, and outputs the results to something you can graph, such as a csv file.